# XMLHttpRequest not working as expected after package electron

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, electron

I have a electron project that uses ffi-napi to integrate some cpp code and uses electron-forge / electron-compile to package the app.

Everything works fine when i run "electron-forge start".

My javascript uses XMLHttpRequest to load in some binary data from a custom file format (*.awd). XMLHttpRequest.responseType is "arraybuffer".

The problem is, that once i use "electron-forge package" and run the resulting app, the XMLHttpRequest in my javascript no longer works as expected. It does not throw a error, but the XMLHttpRequest.result is much smaller than it should be, so the parsing of the binary data fails.

This are the versions of electron-forge / electron-compile that i am using:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "ffi-napi": "^2.4.4",
    "ref": "^1.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4"
  }
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the solution myself.

The problem is with the "electron-compile" module. After running "electron-forge package" it seem to interfere when loading my custom binary files and prevent them from being loaded correctly via XMLHttpRequest.

The solution seems to use the "addBypassChecker" that comes with the electron-compile package to ignore files to be recompiled by electron-compiled if they are not part of the App.

```
import { app } from 'electron';
import { addBypassChecker } from 'electron-compile';

addBypassChecker((filePath) => {
  return filePath.indexOf(app.getAppPath()) === -1;
});
```

more infos here:

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-compile/pull/199